# React Native Cocoapods installation Issues

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

Anyone #with help on how to setup #reactnative #ide on #M1Macbookpro? Tried a number of YouTube tutorials but my problem begins when I start running "npx react-native init " and have problems installing cocoapods, even when I cd > install  #dev #vscode

Followed the react native official installation guide all to no avail. Tried running terminal in rosetta to install cocoapods but still no results. Any help?

This is the error:

```
✔ Downloading template
```

✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./AwesomeProject07/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/

Comment: I was searching for a long time for the same issue. now it's is working fine. try this link. https://blog.aamnah.com/reactnative/macbook-m1-react-native-ios-android-dev-setup

Answer (score 0):

try to run pod install with this command

**sudo arch -x86_64 pod install**

also run this command too

**sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi**